# No instance for Foldable arising from length inside lambda

Tags: haskell, lambda, foldable

first question here and completely a noob on haskell, so please be kind with me :)

I was playing with the question number 6 of [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/21_to_28) haskell exercises

and in the end came to the solution (or something similar I hope) with this code

```
combinations gr lis = filter clean $ sequence $ replicate gr lis
where
    clean string
        | total > gr = False
        | otherwise = True
        where total = sum [ rpt c string | c <- string]
    rpt chr list = length $ filter (== chr) list
```

the part that i like to be highlighted is the function 'rpt' which counts the number of times a character is repeated in a string, for example: 
"aaba" -> [3313] (the 3 comes from the letter a, which repeates 3 times)
"aaccva" -> [332213]

later on I tried to make the function with a lambda and a map resulting in this:

```
rpt chr list = map (\chr -> length $ filter (== chr)) list
```

and at first ghci told me to use FlexibleContext to allow this, but if I do then it yields:

```
<interactive>:7:1:
No instance for (Foldable ((->) [Char]))
  arising from a use of ‘rpt’
In the expression: rpt 'a' string
In an equation for ‘it’: it = rpt 'a' string
```

and here I'am stuck, I have not been able to understand what's happening... what is needed to fix this function?

Comment: This is pretty good structurally for the beginner you say you are, you have a knack for this

Comment: As general advice in these situations, when you get a confusing error message, start adding type annotations stating what you think the types should be.  This will *significantly* improve the error messages.  In fact, it's usually good practice to provide type annotations for all top-level functions to catch these sorts of mistakes as soon as possible.

Comment: This is good for a beginner. A couple of notes: 1) consider `clean string = total <= gr where ...` since using guards or if-then-else to return true/false looks more complex than it needs to be 2) your algorithm for combinations looks correct but suboptimal: you generate many candidates, and you need to filter them out later. Consider this: you can pick k elements from `x:xs` by either skipping `x` (and taking all k elements from `xs`) or choosing `x` (and then taking only k-1 elements from `xs`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely are intending to filter over `list`, so to make your code work, you need to also add `list` as an argument of `filter`:

```
rpt chr list = map (\chr -> length $ filter (== chr) list) list
```

For beginners, I recommend ignoring GHCi's suggestion of `FlexibleContexts`. It often ends up producing error messages like the one you had (or other confusing ones like `No instance for (Num (Int -> Bool))`).

Comment: Proposal: the fix he actually wanted was to include `list` at the end of the mapped function (as in `map (\chr -> length $ filter (== chr) list) list`). Your code produces a list of functions; mine produces a list of numbers.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think you are right. I'll amend the solution accordingly.

Comment: wow such simple solution... thank you @Alec you've helped me a lot!